# JQuery function inside window width function not working

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to prevent my mobile customers from downloading a non-essential 3mb gif after submitting a form. 
The two functions work independently, e.g. console.log("it works") if width > 524. And the img load function works by itself. But not when I combine them like so:

```
if($(window).width() >= 524){
     $('<img src="/img/thank.gif">').load(function() {
        $(this).appendTo('#thankyou-pic');
      });
 };
```

Comment: Just curious, what exactly doesn't work when they are used together?  Doesn't get inside the if block? The anonymous handler for .load doesn't fire? The handler fires but doesn't do what's expected?

Comment: Check out the caveats here if you haven't already: https://api.jquery.com/load-event/. Maybe it's cached? Also it's removed in jQuery 3 so might want to look at doing it another way, anyway.

Comment: You don't even need javascript/jquery for that. You could use css media query. IMHO it's simpler and cleaner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery "load" handler shortcut is deprecated ([source](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/)), and has several caveats to its usage in the ideal case.

As [Maadinsh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1061491/maadinsh) mentioned [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43576097/jquery-function-inside-window-width-function-not-working#comment74212723_43576097) on your question, you may have better luck using CSS3 media queries to load or not load the image.

As an example implementation, you could add this to your CSS for this page:

```
@media (min-width: 524px) {
  #thankyou-pic {
    background-image: url("/img/thank.gif");
  }
}
```

This would apply a background image to your "thankyou-pic" element only when the screen size is larger than 524px wide, pulling the image from the url defined in the CSS rule.

Note: you may need to adjust the URL a bit, as it will now be the location of your "img" folder in reference to where your CSS file lives.